# Qt QToolBar get button added by addAction

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qtoolbar

In Qt when we use the function `addAction` of a `QToolBar`:

```
_LastBar->addAction(QtExtensions::Action(name, icon, func));
```

How could we retrieve the `QToolButton` generated for that action?

Or, if this is not possible, how to find the last button/widget of a `QToolBar`?

Comment: This sounds promising: [`QToolbar::widgetForAction()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#widgetForAction). You may feed it with the `QAction*` returned by `addAction()` and `dynamic_cast<QToolButton*>()` the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the following method which sounds promising: [`QToolbar::widgetForAction()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#widgetForAction).

The `QToolbar::addAction()` returns a `QAction*` with the pointer of created `QAction` instance. This pointer is used with `QToolbar::widgetForAction()` and should return the corresponding `QWidget*`. Knowing that this should be a `QToolButton` we can apply a `dynamic_cast<QToolButton*>` which shouldn't fail.

To check this out, the following MCVE `testQToolBarAddAction.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QToolBar qToolBar;
  QAction *pQAction = qToolBar.addAction(
    "Click Me", [](bool) { qDebug() << "Clicked."; });
  QToolButton *pQToolBtn
    = dynamic_cast<QToolButton*>(qToolBar.widgetForAction(pQAction));
  qDebug() << "QToolbutton::label:" << pQToolBtn->text();
  qToolBar.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQToolBarAddAction.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQToolBarAddAction.cc

QT = widgets
```

Compiled and tested on [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQToolBarAddAction.pro

$ make

$ ./testQToolBarAddAction 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
QToolbutton::label: "Click Me"
Clicked.
```

[image: snapshot of testQToolBarAddAction]

The `QToolButton` returns the same label like the `QAction` – which should count as proof.